# What are the similarities/differences between force:recordData attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, documentation, lightning-data-service, attribute

I've just completed a few Lightning Component Trailhead modules and the last one discussed the `Lightning Data Service` which introduces `<force:recordData ... />`. For some examples, they use attributes such as **fields, layoutType, targetFields, targetRecord, etc.** After reviewing the Lightning Components documentation, I couldn't find a section on `force:recordData`.

I am hoping for explanations on the following attributes:

- fields
- layoutType
- mode
- recordId
- recordUpdated
- targetRecord
- targetFields
- targetError

On one module **Lightning Data Service** it mentions some of these are optional and can replace each other, but again the documentation is not straight forward on which ones replace one another, and their specific purpose.

Can anyone help clarify this confusion?

Comment: This is the [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification) for `force:recordData`. I assume, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @JayantDas Thank you! I spent too much time on the [older Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_documentation.htm) without realizing this updated page existed.

Comment: I recently realized that the (old) documentation links are broken and that everything now exists there. Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: @JayantDas If you repost the answer as an official comment I will mark this as complete. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you meant other way round (to post the comment as official answer) :) If that's what you meant then -- Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for `force:recordData` can be found on the official documentation link as below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification

Only recently realized that Salesforce has restructured the documentation links which still does not seem to be indexed and are not returned through a search.